# Usar operador lógico con estructura Switch en C

Tags: c

¿Es posible utilizar operadores lógicos en la estructura switch en C?

Algo como esto:

```
switch (num) {
    case (20 | 30):
        printf("Funciona");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede utilizar operadores lógicos, pero **si es posible utilizar un solo bloque como respuesta a coincidencias en varios valores**, que no es exactamente lo mismo que un operador lógico, pero que si sería equivalente a tu ejemplo. Para esto, la sentencia a construir sería:

```
switch (num) {
    case 20:
    case 30:
        printf("Funciona");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Pensé que admitía operadores lógicos como en bash.
Gracias.